# Simple NodeJS server TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'configure'

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've added a configure object to my simple NodeJS socketIO server. I am following the demo in the actual wiki here
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/configuring-socket.io

When I run I get the error

**TypeError: Object # has no method 'configure'**

Why?
This is my complete server.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.configure('', function(){
  io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);
});

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log('connection '+socket);
    socket.on("data",function(d){console.log('data from flash: ',d);});
  socket.emit("message","hello from server");
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
    console.log(' disconnect');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `server.listen(8080)` to

`var io = require('socket.io').listen(server.listen(8080));`

May this will solve.

Thanks